# `Synchronous requests are not supported.` in truffle 4.0

Tags: web3js, truffle

The following code in `truffle` (v4.0-beta) is failing:

```
.then(() => web3.eth.sendTransaction(
        {from: accounts[0], to: swt.address, value: 1e10}))
```

Error: `Synchronous requests are not supported.`

Is there a way to send ETH using asynchronous transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle 4 in it's test framework requires that all functions are `Promise`.
`web3.eth` functions are synchronous. So, to use them in the Truffle framework we need to wrap them:

```
// wraps web3 sync/callback function into a Promise
function web3AsynWrapper (web3Fun) {
  return function (arg) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      web3Fun(arg, (e, data) => e ? reject(e) : resolve(data))
    })
  }
}

exports.sendTransaction = web3AsynWrapper(web3.eth.sendTransaction)
exports.getBalance = web3AsynWrapper(web3.eth.getBalance)
```

The same issue exists when you are connecting using the IPC provider: [Synchronous requests are not supported by the IPC provider](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10703/synchronous-requests-are-not-supported-by-the-ipc-provider)

Comment: do you know if there is a web3 lib already fully wrapped like this? Wondering why this is not per default already the case.

Comment: Yes, web3 v1.0. It is out but still in beta. It comes with other goodies as well: Wallet management, transaction signature, gas analysis...

Answer (score 3):

This is not a truffle issue. This is related to web3. web3 doesn't support synchronous request. You can use `sendTransaction` function implementing callback.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: swt.address, value: 1e10},function(err,txHash){
    if(err){
        console.log("Could not send transaction");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Transaction send successfully. Transaction Hash:",txHash );
    }
})
```